# How to create Navigation Bar (or something similar) in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I need to create the top bar like `Navigation Bar` is xCode?

On the picture below it's a bar with "By Name" text.

[image]

Thanks for every advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that is available in the Corona sample code included with the simulator.  Look under Interface in the Sample Code on your computer. Obviously you need to create all your own images which is tough :( but at least all the code is there!

Keep in mind, Corona only simulates native UI.  Corona does not have native UI UNLESS you use their widget library.

Comment: Thank you! I have find it in WidgetDemo sample project )

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK doesn't have a specific widget for the top navigation bar, but it's a simple rectangle or a rectangle with a gradient which is easy enough to put on the screen with display.newRect() or display.newImageRect().

Any buttons or text you would have to add with the appropriate API calls.